# Android Emulator has different colors than in reality (bug?)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have noticed that if I put a slightly grey background on a view, in the emulator is rendered as white.

Pairing with another developer we realized that all the colors are slightly lighter than what actually has been set in the code.

In the picture you can see the difference between what is shown "live" on the emulator and a screen record of the emulator itself taken with Android Studio.

So the code is correct, also in an actual device the grey is displayed correctly, but the emulator show the result in slightly lighter color. Don't know why.

Anyone knows how to fix this? It's such a pain when you need to have a pixel perfect interface.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yeah i faced with this problem  , it maybe related to devices.

Comment: mhm, so if I create a new emulator with a different base device it might solve the problem?

Comment: Yes you can try it , as i found a hex color has a little different result in some devices.